# Neural Turing Machine Loss Going to NaN

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

**Update: This question is outdated and was asked for a pre 1.0 version of tensorflow. Do not refer to answers or suggest new ones.**

I'm using the tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits function for the loss and it's going to NaN.

I'm already using gradient clipping, one place where tensor division is performed, I've added an epsilon to prevent division by zero, and the arguments to all softmax functions have an epsilon added to them as well.

Yet, I'm getting NaN's mid-way through training.

Are there any known issues where TensorFlow does this that I have missed?
It's quite frustrating because the loss is randomly going to NaN during training and ruining everything.

Also, how could I go about detecting if the training step will result in NaN and maybe skip that example altogether? Any suggestions?

EDIT: The network is a Neural Turing Machine.

EDIT 2: Here's the code for gradient clipping:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr)
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
capped_gvs =\
  [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1.0, 1.0), var) if grad != None else (grad, var) for grad, var in gvs]
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

I had to add the `if grad != None` condition because I was getting an error without it. Could the problem be here?

**Potential Solution:** I'm using tf.contrib.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy for a while now, and so far the loss hasn't diverged. I will test some more and report back.

Comment: As a first idea, try decreasing learning rate.

Comment: I'm using Adam optimizer with gradient clipping so not sure how much changing the learning rate will help. I did try decreasing the learning rate and it still went to NaN. In fact, before decreasing the rate, it finished training without any problems and I thought I had somehow solved the problem - but nope.

Comment: Have you tried adding very small Gaussian noise before each layer?

Comment: Which initializer are you using for weights? Try to use xavier_initializer.

Comment: @vfcosta Truncated normal.

Comment: Any minimal example or test case to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @EricPlaton I've put the code on github. Disclaimer though, I'm quite new at this so I'm not sure if my code follows exactly how the authors intended the architecture to be. It's just trial and error for me.

Comment: You could try adding batch normalization layers

Comment: Do you have an error trace? Reading your code; nothing spotted so far.

Comment: @EricPlaton No errors, sometime during training (and not always even), the loss goes to nan, and from then onward stays nan.

Comment: @SilverSlash No answer for now, sorry. I've asked for an error trace, as you pin point a potential problem with `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`. How did you narrow down the problem to that utility? Looking at the code, it seems fine around there. Digging deeper on how it is fed (when calling `_get_losses`, etc.) requires more time, and that would help if you could narrow down more (and perhaps lead you to the answer). Note: I did not check against the original NTM model.

Comment: @EricPlaton I don't think the problem lies in tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits, I just mentioned it because I thought it might be relevant information and since I don't use it often. I think the problem might lie in the init_state method of the NTMCell class.

Comment: Added my code for clipping gradients. There might be a mistake there.

Answer (score 2):

Use 1e-4 for the learning rate.  That one always seems to work for me with the Adam optimizer.  Even if you gradient clip it can still diverge.  Also another sneaky one is taking a square root since although it will be stable for all positive inputs its gradient diverges as the value approaches zero.  Finally I would check and make sure all inputs to the model are reasonable.

Comment: There indeed are square root computations in the graph, but the square roots are computed as part of the l2 norm of tensors. So I'm using tf.square() on the tensors before taking their square roots, and even after squaring I've added an epsilon to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Try using the tf.nn.l2_loss function.  It does not matter that you square something before the sqrt.  It will still diverge.  You only get divergence after training a while since that is when the errors get small and the graident of the sqrt diverges.

Comment: Can't use tf.nn.l2_loss as it doesn't take a dim argument. It sums every element of a tensor, I need to do over a specific dimension.

Comment: I used even 1e-9 still getting the error. Only I made batch_size very large and till now no error

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since this was asked, but I'd like to add another solution that helped me, on top of clipping. I found that, if I increase the batch size, the loss tends to not go close to 0, and doesn't end up (as of yet) going to NaN. Hope this helps anyone that finds this!

Comment: For me, that is only "postpaning" the error, it does again come

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the NaN values were a result of NaN in the training datasets , while I was working on multiclass classifier , the problem was a dataframe positional filter  on the [ one hot encoding ] labels.

Resolving the the target dataset resolved my issue - hope this help someone else.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

for me i added epsilon to parameters inside a log function.

i no longer see the errors but i noticed a moderate increase in the model training accuracy.